# PowerShell: How can I remove a literal "\n" from a string and replace with actual newline

Tags: powershell, escaping, string-literals, powershell-core

I have a string like this: `hello\nworld`  where the `\n` is not symbolic for a newline but is literal. How to I change that string to have an actual newline?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do a literal replacement, I'd suggest using [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) over the `-replace` regex operator:

```
$str.Replace("\n", "`n")
```

If you insist on using `-replace`, consider using `[regex]::Escape()` to escape any special sequences in the pattern - this approach will then work for *any* literal pattern, not just `"\n"`:

```
$target = "\n"
$str -replace [regex]::Escape($target),"`n"
```

Comment: Nice. This is even easier. I had forgotten about the method replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'hello\nworld'
$str = $str -replace '\\n',"`n"
```

Note, (a) the double quotes are required, (b) since "-replace" takes a regular expression, we need to escape the backslash by doubling it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, **the following *may be overkill***, but it is required if you want to **support *escaped* `\` characters** in your input string, so that, for instance, `\\n` - an *escaped* `\` followed by a *verbatim* `n` - is replaced with *verbatim* `\n` (rather than by verbatim `\` followed by a newline):

Using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) syntax:

```bash
# Input string with escaped and unescaped '\n' sequences.
$str = '\\n \\\\n \\\nFirst new line. \nNext new line.'

$str -replace '(\\+)n', { 
  $len = $_.Groups[1].Value.Length
  if ($len % 2 -eq 0) { '\' * ($len / 2)     + 'n' }  # escaped \ + verbatim n
  else                { '\' * (($len-1) / 2) + "`n" } # escaped \, if any, + \n
}
```

In *Windows PowerShell*, where using [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) as the substitution operand of `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), isn't supported, direct use of a .NET API ([`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator))) is required:

```bash
# Input string with escaped and unescaped '\n' sequences.
$str = '\\n \\\\n \\\nFirst new line. \nNext new line.'

[regex]::Replace(
  $str, 
  '(\\+)n', 
  { 
    param($m)
    $len = $m.Groups[1].Value.Length
    if ($len % 2 -eq 0) { '\' * ($len / 2)     + 'n' }  # escaped \ + verbatim n
    else                { '\' * (($len-1) / 2) + "`n" } # escaped \, if any, + \n
  }
)
```

Both snippets yield the following verbatim string:

```bash
\n \\n \
First new line. 
Next new line.
```

Note how only the `\n` sequences preceded by either *no* or an *even number* of `\` characters were replaced with actual newlines (produced via PowerShell [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) `` `n `` inside `"..."`, an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)), and how `\\` sequences, i.e. *escaped* `\` chars., were replaced with verbatim `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the in answer. This is the full featured answer to go down to the detail level. I don't recall learning about using a code block as a function argument. That is pretty slick.